# Expressing real numbers in terms of Liouville numbers

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

How to express any arbitrary real number $\alpha$ as sum of two Liouville numbers?

Recalling a Liouville number is a real number such that $ 0<| \alpha - \frac{p}{q}|< \frac{1}{q^n}$ has infinitely many solutions in $\frac{p}{q}$ for all $n \geq 0.$

Explicitely $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b^{n!}}$ such that $a_n=0,...b-1$ and $b\geq 2$ are Liouville numbers.

Given any arbitrary real number $\alpha$ and after considering its decimal expansion how do we construct two Liouville numbers that will add up to $\alpha$?

Comment: This is a result of Erdos, [here](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1962-18.pdf).  In that paper he also shows that ever real is the product of two Liouville numbers.

Comment: @lulu Very interesting. Has such a result also been established for the sum ?

Comment: @Peter  What do you mean?  That paper handles both sum and product.